# How to Auto-generate the Product URL key During Import

Tags: import, avs-fastsimpleimport, ee-1.13.0.2

We are importing products using a PHP script using `AvS_FastSimpleImport` which is an extension of `Mage_ImportExport`.

The CSV files / array do not contain the field `url_key`.

So currently, this value is empty for the products.

We would like to have the URL key auto generated, just as if we enter a product manually in the backend and leave the field empty.

The script already contains a part to load admin events:

```
Mage::getConfig()->loadEventObservers('adminhtml');
Mage::app()->addEventArea('adminhtml');
```

**Edit** This bug is fixed in EE 1.13.1.0

Comment: Did you look into `Enterprise_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product` this seems to build a list of all the current urlkeys.

Comment: I was having a similar problem with my own CSV import module, but it turned out that import wasn't creating any records in the catalog_product_website table. Including a _product_websites column set to 'base' and reindexing after the import fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A basic solution seems to be to set the `url_key` column to the product name.

This will run through `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey_Abstract::beforeSave` which automatically formats the URL key properly (removing spaces and so on).

I would actually expect `\Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey::beforeSave` to be used during the export, because we are on Enterprise, which is not the case.

Even if the Enteprise-only method would be called during import, this would not work, because it checks the database for duplicate URL keys - which is not yet updated during that stage of the import.

Solution: After importing, detect missing URL keys using:

```
$urlKeyMissing = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addWebsiteFilter($website)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',  array('null' => ''), 'left');
```

and update these products (load, setDataChanged, save).

In addition I am setting the following in the `config.xml` of my import module (the standard import-export is disabling the URL key checks)

```
<global>
    <importexport>
        <import>
            <catalog_product>
                <attributes>
                    <url_key>
                        <backend_model>enterprise_catalog/product_attribute_backend_urlkey</backend_model>
                    </url_key>
                </attributes>
            </catalog_product>
        </import>
    </importexport>
</global>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code (refactored ofcouse) to make sure a unique URL key is created:

```
// Unique URL keys
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$urlKey = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_url')->formatUrlKey($productName);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'url_key' AND entity_type_id = 4) AND value = ? and store_id = 0';
$row = $read->fetchRow($sql, array($urlKey));
$idx = 1;
while ($row != false) {
    $urlKey = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_url')->formatUrlKey($productName) . '-' . $idx;
    $idx++;
    $row = $read->fetchRow($sql, array($urlKey));
}
```

**Magento version:** 1.8.0.0-alpha1

After digging in the code Magento seems to handle this in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey` class:

```
     /**
     * Format url_key value
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $object
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();

        $urlKey = $object->getData($attributeName);
        if ($urlKey === false) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($urlKey == '') {
            $urlKey = $object->getName();
        }
        $urlKey = $object->formatUrlKey($urlKey);
        if (empty($urlKey)) {
            $urlKey = Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash();
        }
        $object->setData($attributeName, $urlKey);

        $this->_validateUrlKey($object);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Check unique url_key value in catalog_product_entity_url_key table.
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $object
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     */
    protected function _validateUrlKey($object)
    {
        $connection = $object->getResource()->getReadConnection();

        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from($this->getAttribute()->getBackendTable(), array('count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(\'value_id\')')))
            ->where($connection->quoteInto('entity_id <> ?', $object->getId()))
            ->where($connection->quoteInto('value = ?', $object->getUrlKey()));
        $result = $connection->fetchOne($select);
        if ((int)$result) {
           throw new Mage_Core_Exception(
               Mage::helper('catalog')->__("Product with the '%s' url_key attribute already exists.",
                   $object->getUrlKey())
           );
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: I want to do this only for newly imported products. And it would be great to use the same code as when saving a product.

Comment: I have added the way Magento does this, since that's what you are asking for... I guess you could use the same logic or call the beforesave method yourself.

Comment: thanks for the update - any clue why this is not called during import?

Comment: By the way: In EE 1.13.0.2 `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey` is empty.

Comment: In EE I think the logic is located in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`, it isn't called because the module you use may have work directly against the database...

Comment: The beforeSave is in `\Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey::beforeSave`

Answer (score 1):

What I found is the url generataion for new products in the enterprise import system happens in the file `Enterprise_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product` which extends `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product`.

First it loads an array of all the current url key and linked skus on construct via the function `_initUrlKeys`.

Then when it called `_prepareAttributes` first it will check the url key via `_prepareUrlKey` and then call the parent `_prepareAttributes` function.

```
protected function _prepareUrlKey($rowData, $rowScope, $sku)
{
    if (self::SCOPE_DEFAULT != $rowScope) {
        return $rowData;
    }
    if (!empty($rowData['name']) && empty($rowData['url_key']) && array_search($sku, $this->_urlKeys) === false) {
        $rowData['url_key'] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->formatUrlKey($rowData['name']);
        if (isset($this->_urlKeys[$rowData['url_key']])) {
            $rowData['url_key'] = sprintf(
                '%s-%s',
                $rowData['url_key'],
                substr(Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash(), 0, 6)
            );
        }
        $this->_urlKeys[$rowData['url_key']] = $sku;
    }
    return $rowData;
}
```

So if you update `AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import_Entity_Product` to extend `Enterprise_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product`. In my case I have already rewriten `AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import_Entity_Product` and so I simply added the function I needed into my new class as the function simply add onto the core functionality and do not rewrite them, but I understand why this is not an ideal solution.